# Unable to extend DS.Model from ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my model

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    first_name: null,
    last_name: null,
    gender: null,
    profession: null,
    age: null
});
```

And Firebug gives me 2 errors:

```
TypeError: Ember.EnumerableUtils is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

removeObject = Ember.EnumerableUtils.removeObject;
```

And this for Extending the DS.Model

```
TypeError: DS.Model is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

App.Person2 = DS.Model.extend({
```

Extending Ember.Object works fine with the same Model, i just can not use DS.*

Google had 0 results for those error messages

Comment: Can you reproduce the error messages with this fiddle? It uses latest master versions of Ember.js  and Ember-Data: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DvdVH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is a bad combination of ember-data and ember libs. 
About 4 weeks ago `Ember.ArrayUtils` was renamed to `Ember.EnumerableUtils`. 
I assume you are using a pretty recent version of ember-data but an older version of ember.js. You can either upgrade ember to the latest if you are happy working with the edge or simply do a find and replace in ember-data, you may run into other consistencies though.